# Convert hex into string literal: replacing 0x with \x

Tags: python, string, hex, escaping, data-conversion

I need to send a command comprised of hex values, like so: "\x06\x01\x00\x44".
The string is then encoded into binary, using the built in .encode() function, and sent off into Telnet.

For reasons I do not understand, this does not work if the string is formatted using the other hex formatting (0x instead of \x): "0x060x010x000x44", so I am trying to only use \x.

I need to insert a value into the command before converting it, but I do not know how to take an integer input and convert it into a hexadecimal string literal.

I can do this:

```
input_int = 100
hex_value = hex(input_int)
```

But that just leaves me with hex_value = '0x64', which is not the same as '\x64'.

Is there a shortcut I am missing, or some way to just turn the int straight into a hex literal string?

(I am using Python 2.7, by the way.)

Comment: Consider running this project with python3.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot, the project is limited to 2.7 for now.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out chr() is what I was looking for. It turns the integer value into the ASCII character with the proper value.